# Erroneous Syntax Highlighting for GCC C in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, intellisense

Ever since I downloaded Visual Studio on my computer, syntax highlighting and IntelliSense has been erroneous in VS Code for my C programs. For example, this code

```
int main()
{
   unsigned long long size = 3;

   int a[size];

   return 0;
}
```

has the `size` variable underlined in red in the square brackets. Other things seem off, too. For example, the `__uint128_t` type used to show up in the IntelliSense recommendations, but now it does not. Also, in order to include definitions from the `<math.h>` header file, I need to include `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` now, otherwise VS Code will not recognize any of the macros.

All of the code listed above still compiles just fine for me, but the erroneous syntax highlighting can get a bit annoying. My theory is that the VS Code editor thinks that I am using an MSVC compiler instead of GCC. My friend who doesn't have Visual Studio has none of these problems. I can't think of any other reason for why this is happening.

Is there a way that I can fix this, like maybe changing the compiler options in settings? Thanks.

Comment: this is not standard C, it might be valid using a compiler extension

Comment: relevant (??): https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide ... you may need to write your own gramar.

Comment: @rioV8 This is strictly conforming standard C. What unmentionable substances MSVC might be smoking is another story.

Comment: Variable length arrays are a conditional feature of C; implementations are not required to support it, and MSVC chooses not to.  So it makes sense that its IDE would warn if you try to use them.

Comment: In VS Code you probably have your Intellisense Mode set to a compiler (such as MSVC) that doesn't support that construct. Check the Intellisense Mode setting. I just tried it and noticed mine defaults to MSVC, so I changed it to gcc and that pesky squiggly line went away.

Comment: Btw, I'm using the Microsoft C/C++ Extension, which is what has that setting. If you're using some other VSC plugin, check the settings for that plugin.